# picocontainer for singleton DI

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to use picocontainer for DI but still getting my shared object instantiated several times instead of being automatically managed as a singleton. Here's an example to illustrate. Classes ASteps and BSteps receive a SharedObject instance through their constructors. I expected it to be managed as a singleton by picocontainer: instantiated only once, as per the Cucumber docs. Instead, I see it gets instantiated once for ASteps and once for BSteps:

```
Running my.domain.CucumberRunTest
 INFO [main] (CucumberHooks.java:15) - Executing before()
 INFO [main] (SharedObject.java:11) - SharedObject - instantiated
 INFO [main] (ASteps.java:21) - Executing a_step_one()
 INFO [main] (ASteps.java:26) - Executing a_step_two()
 INFO [main] (ASteps.java:31) - Executing a_step_three()
 INFO [main] (CucumberHooks.java:20) - Executing after()
 INFO [main] (CucumberHooks.java:15) - Executing before()
 INFO [main] (SharedObject.java:11) - SharedObject - instantiated
 INFO [main] (BSteps.java:23) - Executing b_step_one()
 INFO [main] (BSteps.java:28) - Executing b_step_two()
 INFO [main] (BSteps.java:33) - Executing b_step_three()
 INFO [main] (CucumberHooks.java:20) - Executing after()
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
package my.domain;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class ASteps {

final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
SharedObject sharedObject;

public ASteps(SharedObject sharedObject) {
this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
}

@Given("^A step one$")
public void a_step_one() {
log.info("Executing a_step_one()");
}

@When("^A step two$")
public void a_step_two() {
log.info("Executing a_step_two()");
}

@Then("^A step three$")
public void a_step_three() {
log.info("Executing a_step_three()");
}
}

************************

package my.domain;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class BSteps {

final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
SharedObject sharedObject;

public BSteps(SharedObject sharedObject) {
this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
}

@Given("^B step one$")
public void b_step_one() {
log.info("Executing b_step_one()");
}

@When("^B step two$")
public void b_step_two() {
log.info("Executing b_step_two()");
}

@Then("^B step three$")
public void b_step_three() {
log.info("Executing b_step_three()");
}
}

************************

package my.domain;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class CucumberHooks {

final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Before
public void before() {
log.info("Executing before()");
}

@After
public void after() {
log.info("Executing after()");

}
}

*********************

package my.domain;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class CucumberRunTest {

}

**********************

package my.domain;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SharedObject {

final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

public SharedObject() {
log.info("SharedObject - instantiated");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache of the pico container is [reset](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/picocontainer/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/java/picocontainer/PicoFactory.java#L24) between scenarios, when the world is disposed of at the end of the scenario.

This is very much *per design* to avoid state leaking between scenarios and make them isolated so the order of the tests doesn't influence the results.

If you do wish to maintain state between scenario A and scenario B, you either need to handle `SharedObject` yourself, outside of the pico container, or you can make the dependency between these two scenarios explicit – for example by using a [Background](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background).

Comment: Thank you Sébastien, that is very useful. In that case, I don't see much value in using picocontainer (I can get the same result with plain old local variables). I'm creating a test automation framework and want to define different scopes for different kinds of resources: scenario-scoped resources (e.g. a WebDriver instance), or execution-scoped resources (e.g. execution configuration, DB connections, and other immutable or expensive resources). I still need to understand the whole Cucumber JVM life cycle. Would you know any good resources for that? Or is the source code my best option?

Comment: @Pablo I'm afraid I don't know of any – I usually check the cucumber-jvm sources.  They are however well written, so it is somewhat easy to follow.  Check out CucumberScenario#run (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/model/CucumberScenario.java#L36), this is where the magic happens for a scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it's not too late to answer your question.

Actually, you can have what you want.
I saw that you also want to have a single instance of your browser.
You have to use static objects in order to do that.
I created a little class to avoid the Open/close of the driver between each tests. It is managed by picocontainer. In your stepDefinition classes, you have to implement the "same" constructor.

Here is a sample :

```
public class myStepDefinition{
    private Drivers context;
    public myStepDefinition(Drivers context){
        this.context = context;
        // whatever you want to do
    }
}

public class Drivers {
    private static boolean initialized = false;
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void initialize(){
        if (!initialized){
            initialized = true;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://www.myurl.url");
        }
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to go back to you login page or your starting page after each test (passed or failed)

Regards,

Nicolas